# ERROR: The file name must end with .xml or .png

Tags: android-studio

Al tratar de compilar mi aplicacion Android, me muestra el siguiente error:
The file name must end with .xml or .png.

Este error se presenta en todos mis archivos .ini de la carpeta drawable. como puedo resolver este error para que pueda compilar la aplicación en Android Studio?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Elimina esos ficheros ini. Son creados por Windows pero no debería generarlos en esa carpeta

Comment: Muchas gracias a tu comentario, borre los ficheros ini. que estaban mal ubicados y la aplicación se ejecuto sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso no se admite ese tipo de archivo para renderizar assets en android, debes utilizar archivos **.png, jpg** o un archivo de recursos ***xml*** (sobre este último podrias leer un poco mas después).

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> The file name must end with .xml or .png.

Indica que los archivos de recursos que se alojen dentro de `/res/drawable` deben ser únicamente mapas de bits de los siguientes formatos:

> • **.png**
>
> • **.9.png**
>
> • **.jpg**
>
> • **.gif**
>
> • **.xml (únicamente Vector assets)**

Esto lo puedes consultar en la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=es#ResourceTypes).

**El archivo desktop.ini posiblemente no es una imagen por lo tanto no debería encontrarse en el directorio `/res/drawable`**